# Using IN and LIKE in a search and replace query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some fields in a MYSQL database with the following content:

```
eq":"fieldname1+fieldname2+fieldname3+fieldname4/4
```

The numbers are always different, so it could also be something like:

```
eq":"fieldname11+fieldname22+fieldname8/10
```

I would like to run a query to achieve the following:

```
eq":"((fieldname1+fieldname2+fieldname3+fieldname4)/4, 2)
```

I currently have the following query

```
UPDATE wp_wrdydtdbww_cp_calculated_fields_form_settings
    SET form_structure = REPLACE(form_structure, '???', '???')
    WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

The problem is, that there are a lot of additional strings, containing 'fieldname' or '/' as well, so I need to replace the exact structure.
Can somebody help me to modify it?

I tried something with the LIKE pattern (%), but can't get it to work as I always replace other parts of strings as well.

Thanks!

Comment: string manipulation is not the forte of MySQL. trying to use MySQL string functions to perform this manipulation is akin to using an ax to grate cheese, or using a  chainsaw to peel carrots.

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade to MySQL 8.0 and use [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

Comment: You should not be storing them in the database that way. You need to separate those filenames into a separate row in the db then associate them to an id. Do the string manipulation in the server side code.